# Can I expose the API URL to the public in a Python library?

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, pip, pypi

I have built a Django API which has a lot of proprietary algorithms for analyzing stock portfolios. The API is hosted in AWS and this API is also connected to the website where I show the visualizations of the calculated metrics.

I want to build a library to provide these metrics in Python like pandas. Users can install this package using pip install .

In my Python library code, I would expose only the API URL and I will call the API with different parameters and endpoints. Paid users will get a unique access code in email using which only they can access the Python package functions. I don't want to expose my Django API code to the public as the analysis itself requires a lot of stock price data from the Database and also there are a lot of proprietary algorithms.

Does the solution make sense? Should I hide the API URL or just leave it.

Comment: If you are giving a URL to the public that will cost you money if they abuse it, then I would say not.  The way around this is to require a key in the API call that you can validate against a db of paying users.  However, if a paying user is malicious, they will publish the key.  So you can double check against, for example, an IP address.  If the API is getting abused by random individuals, you know who the culprit is.  You therefore need to specify your terms in your user agreement.

Answer (score 1):

Hiding the API URL is [security through obscurity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_through_obscurity) and should be avoided.

To protect your API from being abused by public users, you can either develop your own protection mechanism, e.g: rolling out your custom API key provisioning, with rate limiter, and IP address filtering, etc...

Or you can use AWS [API Gateway](https://aws.amazon.com/api-gateway/) to proxy traffic to your back-end API. API Gateway alone might not be useful, but the services supporting it is really helpful without requiring you to write additional codes

1. API Gateway supports [API Key with Usage Plans](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-api-usage-plans.html), helping to rate limit your authenticated users.
2. You can enable AWS [WAF](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-control-access-aws-waf.html) to protect your API from malicious scripts, or other attacks
3. To make sure that your back-end servers only receive traffic from API Gateway, you can configure a [client-certificate](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/getting-started-client-side-ssl-authentication.html). This way, your server is protected even if your back-end's API URL is publicly exposed.